# How to auto generate sub menus in menu section while generating documentation using jsdoc

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I want to auto generate a sub menu like this while generating documentation using Jsdoc. Is it possible to do so? If yes then show me the way it's been done.[Sample docs with submenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a07X.png)

(Edited) got an easier way to do documentation with ([ReadTheDocs](https://readthedocs.org/))

Comment: do you have any link where you saw this

Comment: I am trying to do the same and facing this issue in one of my on going projects. Do you have any idea